# Qt static build with MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, qt, static

I want to build `Qt` statically with `MySQL`, the problem is, it links to `libmysql.lib` (dymanic), when I configure `Qt` with `MYSQL_LIBS="-lmysqlclient"` (static), it displays errors:

**The config.log:**

```
+ cd /d D:\QtBuild\Src\config.tests\mysql && D:\QtBuild\Src\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += static warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\MySQL\\mysql-5.7.23-win32\\lib C:\\OpenSSL\\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\\lib" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\MySQL\\mysql-5.7.23-win32\\include C:\\OpenSSL\\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\\include" "LIBS += -lmysqlclient" D:/QtBuild/Src/config.tests/mysql
+ cd /d D:\QtBuild\Src\config.tests\mysql && set MAKEFLAGS=& nmake
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26726.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdmysql.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -I. -IC:\MySQL\mysql-5.7.23-win32\include -IC:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\include -ID:\QtBuild\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\cobra\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC064.tmp
> main.cpp
>   link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:mysql.exe @C:\Users\cobra\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC2B7.tmp
> LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
> mysqlclient.lib(xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(libmysql.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(my_time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(ctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4 referenced in function _win32_have_tcpip
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegEnumValueA@32 referenced in function _win_init_registry
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyExA@20 referenced in function _win32_have_tcpip
> mysqlclient.lib(my_default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(log_client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_mess.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_mess.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf referenced in function _my_message_stderr
> mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(log_client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(client_authentication.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::_System_error_category::message(int)const " (?message@_System_error_category@std@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@H@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(sha2_password_common.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(my_default.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__printf referenced in function _my_load_defaults
> mysqlclient.lib(ssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___snprintf referenced in function _ya_SSL_ASN1_TIME_to_string
> mysqlclient.lib(log_client.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__vfprintf referenced in function "void __cdecl error_log_vprint(enum error_log_level::type,char const *,char *)" (?error_log_vprint@@YAXW4type@error_log_level@@PBDPAD@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EqualSid@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sid::operator==(class Sid const &)" (??8Sid@@QAE_NABV0@@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetTokenInformation@20 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Sid::Sid(void *)" (??0Sid@@QAE@PAX@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsValidSid@4 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sid::is_valid(void)const " (?is_valid@Sid@@QBE_NXZ)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__LookupAccountNameW@28 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Sid::Sid(wchar_t const *)" (??0Sid@@QAE@PB_W@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptAcquireContextA@20 referenced in function "public: __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::OS_Seed(void)" (??0OS_Seed@TaoCrypt@@QAE@XZ)
> mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptReleaseContext@8 referenced in function "public: __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::~OS_Seed(void)" (??1OS_Seed@TaoCrypt@@QAE@XZ)
> mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptGenRandom@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::GenerateSeed(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?GenerateSeed@OS_Seed@TaoCrypt@@QAEXPAEI@Z)
> mysql.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
> Stop.
 => source failed verification.
Trying source 6 (type inline) of library mysql ...
+ cd /d D:\QtBuild\Src\config.tests\mysql && D:\QtBuild\Src\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += static warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\MySQL\\mysql-5.7.23-win32\\lib C:\\OpenSSL\\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\\lib" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\MySQL\\mysql-5.7.23-win32\\include C:\\OpenSSL\\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\\include" "LIBS += -lmysqlclient" D:/QtBuild/Src/config.tests/mysql
+ cd /d D:\QtBuild\Src\config.tests\mysql && set MAKEFLAGS=& nmake clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& nmake
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26726.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   del main.obj
>   del mysql.vc.pdb mysql.ilk mysql.idb
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26726.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdmysql.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -I. -IC:\MySQL\mysql-5.7.23-win32\include -IC:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\include -ID:\QtBuild\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\cobra\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC3CF.tmp
> main.cpp
>   link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:mysql.exe @C:\Users\cobra\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC632.tmp
> LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
> mysqlclient.lib(xml.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(libmysql.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(my_time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(ctype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__sprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegCloseKey@4 referenced in function _win32_have_tcpip
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegEnumValueA@32 referenced in function _win_init_registry
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyExA@20 referenced in function _win32_have_tcpip
> mysqlclient.lib(my_default.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(log_client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_winfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_mess.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func
> mysqlclient.lib(my_mess.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf referenced in function _my_message_stderr
> mysqlclient.lib(typelib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(log_client.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf
> mysqlclient.lib(client_authentication.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::_System_error_category::message(int)const " (?message@_System_error_category@std@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@H@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(sha2_password_common.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(my_default.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__printf referenced in function _my_load_defaults
> mysqlclient.lib(ssl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___snprintf referenced in function _ya_SSL_ASN1_TIME_to_string
> mysqlclient.lib(log_client.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__vfprintf referenced in function "void __cdecl error_log_vprint(enum error_log_level::type,char const *,char *)" (?error_log_vprint@@YAXW4type@error_log_level@@PBDPAD@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__EqualSid@8 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sid::operator==(class Sid const &)" (??8Sid@@QAE_NABV0@@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetTokenInformation@20 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Sid::Sid(void *)" (??0Sid@@QAE@PAX@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__IsValidSid@4 referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Sid::is_valid(void)const " (?is_valid@Sid@@QBE_NXZ)
> mysqlclient.lib(common.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__LookupAccountNameW@28 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Sid::Sid(wchar_t const *)" (??0Sid@@QAE@PB_W@Z)
> mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptAcquireContextA@20 referenced in function "public: __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::OS_Seed(void)" (??0OS_Seed@TaoCrypt@@QAE@XZ)
> mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptReleaseContext@8 referenced in function "public: __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::~OS_Seed(void)" (??1OS_Seed@TaoCrypt@@QAE@XZ)
> mysqlclient.lib(random.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptGenRandom@12 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall TaoCrypt::OS_Seed::GenerateSeed(unsigned char *,unsigned int)" (?GenerateSeed@OS_Seed@TaoCrypt@@QAEXPAEI@Z)
> mysql.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'
> Stop.
 => source failed verification.
test config.sqldrivers.libraries.mysql FAILED
looking for library oci
Trying source 0 (type inline) of library oci ...
+ cd /d D:\QtBuild\Src\config.tests\oci && D:\QtBuild\Src\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += static warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\MySQL\\mysql-5.7.23-win32\\lib C:\\OpenSSL\\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\\lib" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\MySQL\\mysql-5.7.23-win32\\include C:\\OpenSSL\\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\\include" "LIBS += -loci" D:/QtBuild/Src/config.tests/oci
+ cd /d D:\QtBuild\Src\config.tests\oci && set MAKEFLAGS=& nmake
> Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.15.26726.0
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdoci.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -I. -IC:\MySQL\mysql-5.7.23-win32\include -IC:\OpenSSL\openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017\include -ID:\QtBuild\Src\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\cobra\AppData\Local\Temp\nmC6EC.tmp
> main.cpp
> .\main.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'oci.h': No such file or directory
> NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
> Stop.
```

I created the batch file for `Qt` configuration:

```
SET /P qtBuildType=Qt build type (shared/static): 
SET /P qtBuildMySqlIncludePath=MySql include path: 
SET /P qtBuildMySqlLibPath=MySql lib path: 
SET /P qtBuildOpenSSLIncludePath=OpenSSL include path: 
SET /P qtBuildOpenSSLLibPath=OpenSSL lib path: 
SET /P qtBuildPath=Enter Qt build path: 
configure.bat -debug-and-release -%qtBuildType% -opensource -nomake tools -nomake examples -no-ltcg -sql-mysql -I "%qtBuildMySqlIncludePath%" -L "%qtBuildMySqlLibPath%" MYSQL_LIBS="-lmysqlclient" -ssl -openssl -openssl-linked -I "%qtBuildOpenSSLIncludePath%" -L "%qtBuildOpenSSLLibPath%" OPENSSL_LIBS="-lUser32 -lAdvapi32 -lGdi32 -lCrypt32" OPENSSL_LIBS_DEBUG="-lssleay32MTd -llibeay32MTd" OPENSSL_LIBS_RELEASE="-lssleay32MT -llibeay32MT" -prefix "%qtBuildPath%"
```

I use `Qt 5.9.6` source code and `Visual Studio 2017`version 15.8.3 on `Windows 10` build 17134.254 and `MySQL` version 5.7.23. I'm building it for `x86` architecture.

Also, I tried to build `MFC` static test project with the `mysqlclient` lib, but the errors are the same:

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBrMc.png)

I want to have this library embedded into the executable. Any ideas how to make it embedded? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by building the `MySQL` & `OpenSSL` static libs. It works well. The issue is resolved.